# Uncaught SyntaxError: in code compiled from Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I used my Build Javascript code in an html file and I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './calculate.js' does not
>   provide an export named 'calculate'

Here is the Typescript. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
class calculate{

    public firstNumber:string;
    public secondNumber:string;
    public resultBox:string;
    constructor() { }


    greet(){
        console.log("Hello my");
    }


}

export {calculate};
```

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
class calculate {
    constructor() { }

    greet() {
        console.log("Hello my");
    }
}
exports.calculate = calculate;
```

Here is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script  type="module">

import {calculate} from './calculate.js'
 var cal= new calculate();
cal.greet();
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are compiling to commonjs module format. Specify module code generation to be "ES2015" by setting `"module":"ES2015"` in config or using `--module` cli argument.

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=2&module=5#code/MYGwhgzhAExiwCu4AuBTA3gWAFC+gdAA6IBGIAlsNAGYUBOEKAcogLalr0BcT9FAOwDmAbnyES5KtAhpgAewEATVhy68U-YWJyFiZStXpoIyFACF5ADw1bR4ggoF9EwFPPoAKAJTQM0AF9cYN1CIWM0FB9sUL1HRQh5EDQAOhB5IU8AIgAJNBB06DYATyzvHT0gvGqq3DQrIg8UPzgEZDB0AJEgA)